# How to create a model object with OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, chat

I have a chat application and I'm trying to save a message. My message model has a OneToOneField, I'm doing this because I want to display a profile image with the message in templates.
Here is my code.....

**Consumers.py** - here is where the message should save

```
@sync_to_async
def save_message(self, username, room, message):
    Message.objects.create(author = username, room = room, content = message)
```

**Models.py** - here is my Message and Profile model

```
class Message(models.Model):
    author = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date_added', )

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

And here is a part of my **Template** where I want to display the messages

```
    <main>
    <div id="chat-text">
        <div id=message> 
            {% for m in messages %}
                <img id="imageid" src="{{ m.author.profile.image.url }}"> <b id="b2" style="color: rgb(252, 93, 93);"> {{m.author}}</b> <br>
                </b> {{ m.content }} <br> 
            {% endfor %} 
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div id="message-box">
        <div class="input-container">
            <input id="file-send" type="button">
            <input id="input" placeholder="Type a message here..." type="text">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

The code above doesn't work and I get an error *Cannot assign "'admin'": "Message.author" must be a "User" instance.* So my question is, how can I create this object with the user instance and get it saved in my database so I can display it with the profile picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with this line:

```
Message.objects.create(author = username, room = room, content = message)
```

Indeed, `author` is supposed to be an `User` object and I guess that `username` is a `String`.

You should get your User object first, with something like that:

```
user = User.objects.get(username = username)
Message.objects.create(author = user, room = room, content = message)
```

Besides, you probably **don't** want to use a `OneToOneField` to link the `Message` model and the `User` model. Indeed, it would mean that an user can write only ONE message.

Use a `ForeignKey` instead, that will not change anything in your template.

Comment: @IceSpeaker Cool! I'm glad I could have helped. Could you please mark the question as answered by marking this answer as correct? You can have more explanations about that here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work